# no matching function for call to 'TaskTred::TaskTred(TaskRun*)'

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

На аналогичную конструкцию другого типа не ругается. В чём может быть проблема и как её устранить?

```
class TaskTred : public QThread
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  TaskTred(){}

  void run(){exec();}

};

error: no matching function for call to 'TaskTred::TaskTred(TaskRun*)'
       taskTreadList << new TaskTred(this);
                                         ^
  QList <TaskTred*> taskTreadList;
  taskTreadList << new TaskTred(this);
```

Comment: Конструктор `TaskTred` не имеет параметров, но Вы пытаетесь впихнуть туда `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, собственно, мне остается только повторить то, что уже сказал компилятор. У вас нет конструктора `TaskTred::TaskTred(TaskRun*)`. Предположу, что должно быть так:

```
class TaskThread : public QThread{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TaskThread(QObject *parent = 0):
        QThread(parent)
    {}
//...   
};
```

Если я правильно вас понял и `TaskRun` унаследован от `QObject`, и вы пытаетесь передать его в качестве родителя

Answer (score 2):

Вы создаёте экземпляр класса следующим образом:

```
new TaskTred(this);
```

— то есть с использование конструктора, принимающего указатель типа переменной `this` ( в данном случае `TaskRun`).

Соответственно, компилятор пытается найти именно такой конструктор и закономерно не находит (объявлен только конструктор без параметров), о чём вам и сообщает (выделение моё):

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 'TaskTred::TaskTred(TaskRun*)'
>                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```